# Unusual error while browsing Opera

Tags: opera

While watching a YouTube video an error message popped up in a dialog box which I have never seen before. I had no other applications running nor any unusual programs running in the background.

[image: Has anyone encountered this error before?]

Comment: From https://support.symantec.com/us/en/article.tech12638.html : An error occurred while reading or writing to the file ; Are you able to play the video after this pop-up/error?

Comment: Yes, everything continued working fine, the pop up was just a bit surprising and unusual. At first i suspected something had been installed on my computer but had encountered an error but i can't find any evidence of malicious/unknown software.